curl to fetch data from ftp server do not work
I am trying to download data from https://data.tpdc.ac.cn/en/data/30131436-88d1-4be3-8e3d-14905a29d6d6/
I am using curl -u download_68313574:22193606 'ftp://ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn:6201/SM_1km_Month/*'  -o . but it does not respond with RETR response:550
Any help is appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: Downloading file from FTP using cURL. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For me curl report

curl: (78) The file does not exist

I am not sure curl (with above command) can handle and download subdirectories
But I try with wget with command:
wget -r ftp://download_68313574:22193606@ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn:6201/SM_1km_Month/*

and work fine for me:
--2024-10-24 19:49:57--  ftp://download_68313574:*password*@ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn:6201/SM_1km_Month/*
           => ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/.listing’
Resolving ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn (ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn)... 210.72.14.201
Connecting to ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn (ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn)|210.72.14.201|:6201... connected.
Logging in as download_68313574 ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /SM_1km_Month ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.

ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_     [ <=>                                          ]   1,52K  --.-KB/s    in 0,006s

2024-10-24 19:50:00 (260 KB/s) - ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/.listing’ saved [1559]

Removed ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/.listing’.
--2024-10-24 19:50:00--  ftp://download_68313574:*password*@ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn:6201/SM_1km_Month/2000/*
           => ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/2000/.listing’
==> CWD (1) /SM_1km_Month/2000 ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.

ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_     [ <=>                                          ]   1,19K  --.-KB/s    in 0,006s

2024-10-24 19:50:01 (199 KB/s) - ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/2000/.listing’ saved [1220]

Removed ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/2000/.listing’.
--2024-10-24 19:50:01--  ftp://download_68313574:*password*@ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn:6201/SM_1km_Month/2000/SM.1km.Month.200002.Global.v001.tif
           => ‘ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+6201/SM_1km_Month/2000/SM.1km.Month.200002.Global.v001.tif’
==> CWD not required.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR SM.1km.Month.200002.Global.v001.tif ... done.
Length: 423861286 (404M)

          ftp2.tpdc.ac.cn+62   0%[                                              ] 136,51K   112KB/s


<snip>

